# Torsion Points under SL-2(Z/nZ)

Tags: elliptic-curves

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Torsion Points under SL_2(Z/nZ)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/65271/torsion-points-under-sl-2z-nz)

I would like to rephrase a question I asked three days ago and was closed for the unclear presentation.

Taking $T \in E[p]$, a point in the p-torsion of the elliptic curve and looking at the right action of $SL_2({\mathbb Z}/p{\mathbb Z})$ on $T$ for prime $p$, one can easily see that you obtain again all points in $E[p]$ equally many times. The action is described as follows:

$$ \Big(\frac{m}p \quad \tau+ \frac{n}p \Big) 
    \left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\\  c & d \end{matrix} \right) = 
    \Big(\frac{ma+nc}p  \quad  \tau+ \frac{mb+nd}p \Big) $$

Now what would happen when we take $T \in E[n]$ where $n$ is an integer and look at the right action of $SL_2({\mathbb Z}/n{\mathbb Z})$?   Do we also get again all the points in $E[n]$ equally many times?  If not, why?

Comment: I believe that the right thing to do in such cases is to go to meta, present the new version of the question and ask people to reopen the old question with the revised statement.

Comment: Closed question is: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/65271/torsion-points-under-sl-2z-nz-closed

Comment: What is the role of the elliptic curve? I don't think the answer will change if you simply consider the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ on $(\mathbb{Z}/n)^2$.

Comment: Do you want $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ acting, or $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p)$?

Comment: The action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ preserves the order of a point, so the statement cannot be true if $n$ is composite.

Comment: This is what you need to do: First, register an account, or find a way to maintain your openID, so you don't create new accounts all the time.  When you've done this, flag your old question for moderator attention so the accounts can be merged.  Then, edit your old question into something that makes sense.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I need to know both.  First for the action under $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$

Comment: This is not an answer, but an (unsuccessful) attempt to clarify the question. You might want to delete this "answer" and edit your question to clarify. The mathematical issue is this: in your question you seem to be saying that $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})$ is acting on $E[n]$ -- presumably you mean the action of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / p \mathbb{Z})$ on $E[p]$ for $p$ prime, and of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / n \mathbb{Z})$ on $E[n]$ for general $n$. 

Comment: See my comment below the question.